Cannot resolve Unity's Newtonsoft.Json UPM package in Rider
I've just started making a Unity game after many years.
I'm trying to use Newtonsoft.Json for deserializing a geojson file with GeoJSON.Net, so I downloaded Unity's package (com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@3.2) in the Package Manager.
After installing it and opening the project in Rider, I cannot import it in my script. Rider doesn't see it as a reference, and it cannot resolve it. It is listed in the Packages tab and in the manifest, but it is not listed in the References.
I've restarted Rider multiple times and reinstalled the package but it didn't solve the problem. What am I missing to do here?


Hi, did you manage to solve this?

To fix IntelliSense and resolve the package, I had to delete the Library folder.

Clicking Unity Settings | External Tools | Regenerate project files should help update references in this case
